# Multiple selection in Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a created a pivot table and have 1000 "Part numbers" Under "Row Labels". It is difficult for the user to search and select multiple part numbers every time. It is a tedious job to find Part numbers as there are many which are identical with only one or numbers different.

[image]

For example in the above image can i select North America and South America without using check boxes. I mean is there a way to select them by placing a comma/ semi colon E.g. 'North America','South America' or  'North America';'South America' and paste it in the search option to filter.

Your expert advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use wildcard (*) in search box.

i.e. in your example you can use * around word america or ameri etc.

Comment: No i cannot see wild card search..... I would want to select both North and South America at a time.

Comment: type *america* in your search box.